# How to make neutron activation analysis online or with free software?

Tags: radioactivity, neutrons

i want to make a neutron activation analysis for different crystals. (MnWO4, TbMnO3, and others) how can i do this with free or open source software? 
Can someone recommend a online calculator for this task?

I do not know the precise isotope ratio, so i have to make my estimation with 
natural ratio of isotopes in the compound.

I want to estimate the activity after investigation in a neutron beam.

Thank you and kind regards

Comment: The question is unclear. Are you trying to estimate/simulate the activation that will occur for after exposure to some defined neutron flux or to interpret the output of some detector system that has been used to count the activity of a previously exposed sample?

Comment: Hopefully AlanSE will be along as I believe he knows some of these tools. The activation cross-section of such materials have been a subject of extensive investigation since at least the 1960s. It would help anyone trying to answer the question to know the energy of the beam and something about the thickness of the target. Neutrons are strange critters and change their behavior enormously across various energy regimes.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this program called Activity Predictor. The Activity Predictor calculates activities, exposure rates and gamma spectra of activated samples for NAA experiments. Create your own compounds from predefined elements and dont forget to edit reactor.xml for neutron fluence values.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/activitypredict/

Dagistan